Scaling and Feature Transformations that are Non Symmetrical for Classification
I want to transform some feature values within my model using a cube root transformation, for the purposes of easing some skewness in my data. However, I've noticed that after I cube root certain features, scale them, then train my model - that when I begin testing the probabilities returned for test cases, mutually exclusive events do not have a probability of adding to 1 (for binary classifcation).
This is due to the fact that after a cube root transformation, my scaling does not maintain symmetry amongst negative values. E.G, say I have a feature X in which I cube root, then scale. If I were to then have a value within X say X_1, the transformations of Scaled(cube_root(X_1)) != -Scaled(cube_root(-X_1)).
Note that I used a RobustScaler, which I believe may be one of the issues surrounding why the scaling is assymetrical as well.
Subsequently this leads to my classification probabilities summing to values greater than 1, as when I run my probability predictions they use features which are not negatively symmetric. How should I deal with this issue?
